# How to create a facebook application without any canvas or gui

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

I want o create a simple facebook application without any canvas or GUI.I want to access the details of app users,post to their wall,access their friends profile etc,Without their presence i mean access their data's any time.I know only PHP.
I am a beginner to Facebook applications.Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Without any GUI is not totally possible. You will need a method of prompting the user to either:

1. authorise your app, or
2. authorise the post to the wall.

Those actions both happen through a gui (web page, remote app etc). Doesn't have to be a webpage, but has to be something that can prompt the user - check out the available APIs for the login. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Once you've got over those hurdles, then it's possible with the tokens, although when tokens become invalid, you'll need to again prompt the user to authorise (back to the gui - and you need to get them to visit/click your link).

Comment: Can i do all this automatically ??

Comment: Nope - you need to develop it. The link above, right near the top, has the APIs that Facebook provide. If you're new to programmming, then select one and run with it. (I'd go with PHP as it's relatively easy [after the first one!] and there's a lot of help around). But you still will need some gui/interface no matter which one you choose.

Comment: What happen to the tokens after 60 days ?

Comment: No longer useful - they will fail. There are also a variety of reasons they will fail before 60 days, so you need to test each and every time.